# config prod, config stage and keys files are good practice?

Tags: node.js, github, configuration

I am using config files to store defaults and passwords/tokens/keys.
Defaults are no problem to be public.
Obviously I want passwords to remain secret.
I mean - not to push the to GitHub.

I thought about make a **configs** directory contains the following files:

`common.js` everybody can see. `keys.js` passwords/tokens/keys. Shouldn't be pushed to GitHub - using .gitignore file to prevent this. `keys-placeholder.js` should contain just placeholders so who clones the project should understand to create `keys.js` file and place his real passwords.

Is it a good practice? How do you hide passwords from pushing to GitHub and also make it comfortable to use when build the project for first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) for public app configuration/constants and `.env` file and [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package for secrets.

Then add `.env` in `.gitignore`.

So example project would be

```
config // app configuration/constants
 - prod.json
 - dev.json
 - test.json
.env // secrets
src/
 - models
 - app.js
 ...
```

----- added -----

Why don't you put the config in the src dir?

A: Of course it's totally up to you where to put your `config` folder.
It's just a matter of preference.

What about staging config?

A: Like question#1, you can add `staging.json` under `config`.

If you don't provide any placeholder file for .env, how do I know which passwords should I fill in this file?

A: Typical `.env` file looks like below.

```
API_CREDENTIAL=your api credentials
DB_PASSWORD=your db password
```

How do you lazyload the prod/dev config files to the node app?

A: I don't see much benefit for lazyloading small json files.
If you're asking specific how to guide for `config` and `dotenv` library,
please refer to their Github repository.([config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config), [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv))

Comment: 1. Why don't you put the config in the src dir? 2. what about staging config? 3. if you don't provide any placeholder file for .env, how do I know which passwords should I fill in this file? Or create it from first of all? 4. How do you lazyload the prod/dev config files to the node app? I see that they are json files.